# Has the likelihood of getting a lower interest rate by calling & asking been reduced by recent credit card regulations?

Tags: united-states, credit-card, legislation

Have the recent CARD act made reduced the likelihood of getting a rate reduction if you call and ask the card company's service department?

Comment: What have you got to lose? It never hurts to try regardless of your odds.

Comment: For the record, I called Capital One today (with whom I've had an account for 10 years) and got a 7% rate reduction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know that this can actually be answered objectively.  Maybe it can with some serious research.  (Read: data on what the issuers have been doing since the law went into affect.)

Personally, I think the weak economy and general problems with easy credit are a bigger issue than the new rules.  Supposedly, there is evidence that card issuers are trying to make up for the lost income due to the new regulations with higher fees.  I believe that your credit rating and history with the issuer is a larger factor now.  In other words, they may be less likely to lower your rate just to keep you as a customer or to attract new customers.

[According to The Motley Fool](http://www.fool.com/investing/general/2010/05/18/how-the-card-act-killed-credit-access.aspx), issuers dropped their riskiest customers as a result of the new regulations.

[Some say](http://articles.moneycentral.msn.com/Banking/CreditCardSmarts/card-act-what-to-know.aspx) that new laws simply motivated the issuers to find new ways to "gouge" their customers.

Here are two NYTimes blog posts about the act:

http://bucks.blogs.nytimes.com/2010/02/22/what-the-credit-card-act-means-for-you/

http://bucks.blogs.nytimes.com/2010/07/22/the-effects-of-the-credit-card-act/

As JohnFx states, it does not hurt to ask.